# C++ an array of pointers to the base class

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, variable-assignment

There are several classes which are made in different files. 
Here are the class name: Hospital class and patient class.
Basically, for hospital class, it has array of pointers for patient which can store the information of patient based on their patient type. For patient class(base class) has four derived classes as follows: male, female, inpatient, outpatient. What I am trying to do is, in hospital class, I want to assign the object according to the patient type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Hospital.h"
#include "Female.h"
#include "Male.h"
#include "Inpatient.h"
#include "Outpatient.h"

using namespace std;

Hospital::Hospital(const char * name, int capacity)
{
    hospitalName=name;
    patientCapacity=capacity;
    totalPatients=0;
}

void Hospital::determinePatientType()
{
    int selection;
    cout << "What is the patient type?" << endl;
    cout << "1. Female" << endl;
    cout << "2. Male" << endl;
    cout << "3. Outpatient" << endl;
    cout << "4. Inpatient" << endl;
    cin >> selection;

    if(selection==1)
    {
        patients = new Patient[totalPatients];
        Female* female = new Female();
        patients = female;
    }
    else if(selection==2)
    {
        patients = new Patient[totalPatients];
        Male* male = new Male();
        patients = male;
    }
    else if(selection==3)
    {
        patients = new Patient[totalPatients];
        Outpatient* outpatient = new Outpatient();
        patients = outpatient;
    }
    else
    {
        patients = new Patient[totalPatients];
        Inpatient* inpatient = new Inpatient();
        patients = inpatient;
    }
    totalPatients++;

}
```

This is my code, but I am not sure if it's correct or not.
And I will upload the class diagram for your understanding what I am doing.
Thank you for your assistance in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSWYP.png)

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: Get rid of the dynamic memory allocation madness and replace it with `std::vector` before you try to do anything else with the code. Also remove the other `new`s.

Comment: `>>but I am not sure if it's correct or not` Well, you have a pointer `patients` which points to array of `Patient`s and then you assign to it various pointers of types other than `Patient *`. So probably not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No your code is not correct.

Lets take a look at this code snippet:

```
if(selection==1)
{
    patients = new Patient[totalPatients];
    Female* female = new Female();
    patients = female;
}
```

With

```
patients = new Patient[totalPatients];
```

you allocate an array of `totalPatients` objects. You make `patients` point to the first element of that array.

Then two lines down you do

```
patients = female;
```

That *reassigns* the variable `patients` to point to the *single object* `female`.

You will lose the original memory from the first allocation, which will lead to a *leak*. It will most likely *also* lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if you then use `delete[] patients` since `patients` no longer point to an array.

Unless your exercise is to lean how to use pointers and dynamic memory allocation, you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

---

There's also another potential issue, and that relates to[*object slicing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) and polymorphism (if the classes are polymorphic, i.e. they have `virtual` member functions).

If you solve the first problem the natural way, by doing e.g.

```
patients[totalPatients] = female;
```

Or if you use a `std::vector<Patient>` and do a simple `push_back(female)`.

Then you *slice* the `female` object, and lose all data specific for the `Female` class. And since you no longer have a `Female` objects, all virtual functions will think they are called on a `Patient` object, making polymprphism not working either.

To solve this problem you should have a vector (or array) of *pointers* to the base `Patient` class. Like e.g. `std::vector<Patient*>`.

Or better yet use a *smart pointer* like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) as in `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Patient>>`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, yea I am trying to use array of pointers, but I do not know how to use it. Could you let me know in case of mine to store the derived object to the patient object in hospital , if you do not mind?

Comment: @성기덕 Unless the purpose is to use pointers and your own dynamic allocation, then see the usage of `std::vector`. Otherwise, to make an "array" of pointers, you already know how to make an array of (non-pointer) objects, now think a little how an array of pointers to those objects would look like. Remember that you don't want an array of `Patient`, you want an array of `Patient*`.